# "There's no Qt version assigned to this project for platform Win32" - visual studio plugin for Qt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I have a Qt project I am working on in Visual Studio 2010, with the Qt Visual Studio Add-in (for Qt 4.8).  The project is running fine on my work machine, and I am trying to run it on my home machine.  When I try to build, I get the following error:

> There's no Qt version assigned to this project for platform Win32.
>
> Please use the 'change Qt version' feature and choose a valid Qt
>   version for this platform.

However, it's set up to use a valid Qt version (another project I'm working on at home uses this plugin as well).  Why is this occurring?  When I got to Qt -> Qt Options, I see a valid version (4.8.0).  Thanks

Comment: Nope.  The project has been 32 bit the whole way through.  Good suggestion, though

Comment: The version path referenced in xxxxx.vcxproj.user has to match the version and installation location on the home machine. You can edit your vcxproj.user file to reflect the correct installation location.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Did you select a proper Qt version in the Qt settings of your project?

More detailed: 
If you right-click on the project there should be a "**Qt Project Settings**" option (or similar - I use the german version) near the end of the context menu. In there you can set the Qt version that this specific project uses. Is this one possibly not set correctly?

Comment: I selected the right QT version for my project from the QT5 menu, but I still got this error. The problem was that I had multiple projects using QT, I had to check them all to make sure they used the correct QT version.

Comment: I found that my projects had the correct version, but I had to right click on the solution and select "Change Solution's Qtversion" at the bottom of the context menu and the problem was solved.

Comment: Mine had the version selected as `6.3.1_msvc2019_64` and when I clicked the dropdown list it showed just `6.3.1` so I selected that it solved the problem.

Answer (score 32):

Solution:

1. Right click your project;
2. **Qt Project Settings**;
3. Under the **Properties** tab, you will find the option **Version**;
4. change it to a proper value;

Now, go ahead with your project.

Hope to help

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem with a x64 Visual Studio 2019 solution on Windows using Qt 5.15.0. Based on the answer from @Fabian and the excellent comment from @sitting-duck:

- Install the `Qt VS Tools` extension
- Select `Extensions > Qt VS Tools > Qt Options`
- On the `Qt Versions` tab click `Add`
- Set "Version Name" to something like "Qt-5.15.0"
- Set "Path" to "[QT-PATH]\5.15.0\msvc2019_64"
- Open `Project Properties > Qt Project Settings > General > Qt Installation`
- Ensure this is set to "Qt-5.15.0" and close Project Properties
- Right-click the solution (in the `Solution Explorer` tab) and select `Change Solution's Qt Version`
- Ensure `Qt-5.15.0` is selected

You should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Open vcxproj file in a notepad, look for QtVersion...something=...
Ensure that the version value is really 4.8.0 (or whatever is your actual QT SDK version).

Answer (score 2):

I found this issue too. and I found the solution . 
you must keep the Qt version name is  exactly same with the project create using.
which you think u can change freely,but actually not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move Qt project between different computers, it's a good idea to use the qt project file, and not the MSVC (.vcxproj) one. So when you move from your work machine home, create a .pro file (in the Qt menu, you find the neccessary options to do that), and then load the .pro file at home, again using the Qt menu inside MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing this could be is the platform being used is not the platform you think it is.  In MSVC right-click on project, select properties, and then press configuration manager. Then check that all configurations and platforms are as you expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem during migration from Qt5.9 to Qt5.10.
We have a solution (Visual Studio) which consists of many projects. Some of them have QtVersion = "Qt5.9" and others have QtVersion = "Qt5.7" (yes, it were inaccurate project settings)

So, after I change all Qt project's settings from 5.9 to 5.10 automatically and remove Qt5.7 from versions list - I got the same error. This error was fixed trivially - I just add back Qt5.7 to the versions list (temporary until ALL projects' Qt version was not changed to 5.10).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I ported a Visual Studio project, with all its files (including `.sln`, `.vcxproj`, etc) to another computer using git. When I set everything up on the new computer, I accidentally selected a different folder for the Qt executables in VS (I selected `C:\Qt\5.9.9\winrt_x86_msvc2017` instead of `C:\Qt\5.9.9\msvc2017_64`). When I double-checked which I had selected on the original computer, and then selected the same on the new computer, all was good.

To select a Qt folder: `Extensions -> Qt VS Tools -> Qt Options -> Add -> Path` (Version Name is auto-filled once you select the path).

This all describes the process using Visual Studio 2019, with the Qt plugin found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools2019).

Answer (score 0):

You could follow AlainD's instruction.
It work for me.
Just Right-click on Solution -> Change Solution's Qt Version
It will make change for its all projects.