# Qt Addin: Attempt to add newer Qt version "There's no Qt version assigned to project"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, qt5

I am trying to create a internal installer for our used Qt version.

Previously we took Qt 5.12.5 (installed via offline installer) and bundled the installed directories into a zip file. After unpacking the 'Qt install dirs' (`msvc2017` and `msvc2017_64`) on the target machine we would set the registry entries at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Digia\Versions\<version name>` so the version would be available from within Visual Studio 2017 and the Qt VsAddin (version 2.10.1).

Now i am attempting to use a inhouse build like before, but when creating a default console application i get the error `There's no Qt version assigned to project`.
This may seem connected to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452721/theres-no-qt-version-assigned-to-this-project-for-platform-win32-visual-stu) but it isn't. I have the version set correct in the Visual Studio project but it fails to find it due to some file or info missing in the copied directories.

Do you have a hint on what could cause the message?